# Karma, Jasmin test error Angular cli

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I want to test my application with karma and jasmine. But I am getting following error but I don't know what is the problem?
I am using Angular CLI with Angular4

> ERROR in
>   /home/tony/Desktop/test/node_modules/rxjs/observable/FromEventObservable.d.ts
>
> ERROR in
>   /home/tony/Desktop/test/node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts
>   (15,63): Cannot find name 'WebSocket'.
>
> ERROR in
>   /home/tony/Desktop/test/node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts
>   (27,13): Cannot find name 'WebSocket'.
>
> ERROR in
>   /home/tony/Desktop/test/node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts
>   (28,32): Cannot find name 'Event'.
>
> ERROR in
>   /home/tony/Desktop/test/node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts
>   (29,33): Cannot find name 'CloseEvent'.
>
> ERROR in
>   /home/tony/Desktop/test/node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts
>   (32,63): Cannot find name 'WebSocket'.
>
> ERROR in
>   /home/tony/Desktop/test/node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts
>   (36,23): Cannot find name 'MessageEvent'.
>
> ERROR in /home/tony/Desktop/test/src/services/login.service.ts
>   (34,11): Cannot find name 'localStorage'.
>
> (11,114): Cannot find name 'HTMLCollection'.
>
> /* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */

Here I am testing the app.component.ts

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
 import {
     TestBed,
     ComponentFixture,
     async
 } from '@angular/core/testing';
 import {
     RouterTestingModule
 } from '@angular/router/testing';
 import {
     HttpModule
 } from '@angular/http';
 import {
     NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
 } from '@angular/core';
 import {
     AppComponent
 } from './app.component';


 let component: AppComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture < AppComponent > ;

 describe('App: Tmp', () => {
     beforeEach(() => {
         TestBed.configureTestingModule({
             imports: [HttpModule, RouterTestingModule],
             declarations: [AppComponent],
             providers: [],

             schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
         }).compileComponents();

         fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
         component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
     });

     it('should create the app', () => {
         expect(component).toBeTruthy();
     });

 });
```

Comment: We need some code to help you here. My first guess would be that you forgot to import `rxjs/Observable`

Comment: Ok, but then my application would not work I think...

Comment: Why not ? You only import one thing. I won't break your app ...

Comment: Ok, see above? I added the app.component.spec.ts for testing. But where should I add the rxjs/Observable?

Comment: Oh ok. That's not where your error comes from. Your error comes from an NPM package, which is rxjs. Did you do npm install for starters ? Because it's clearly missing something.

Comment: I do npm install or what you mean? Should I update it and then again?

Comment: Look at your errors : they all come from node_modules. You clearly miss the package ! So yes, install the package and try again

Comment: No chance. I dowgraded typscript. Updated npm but not working